# jquery download a pdf file then redirect to another page but same window

Tags: jquery, redirect, download

here my html

```
<a class="downloadLink" href="http://domainname.com/sample.pdf"></a>
```

here is my jquery

```
jQuery(".downloadLink").click(
    function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();

        //open download link in new page
        window.open( jQuery(this).attr("href") );


        //redirect current page to success page
        window.location="http://domainname.com/new-location";
        window.focus();
    }
);
```

This code is works file but need it to download the pdf the in same window then redirect to the new location with the same window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout jQueryFiledownload plugin (see the links to the documentation below), it will explain and resolve the issue you are having.

jQuery File Download is a cross server platform compatible jQuery plugin that allows for an Ajax-like file download experience that isn't normally possible using the web.

- http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/
- http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com
- https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Hope this helps, Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Though it is late, I think this might help for those who bump into this later.

```
jQuery('.downloadLink').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //open download link in new page
    var win = window.open( jQuery(this).attr("href") );

    //redirect current page to success page
    window.location="http://domainname.com/new-location";
    win.close();
});
```